# sqlite read item failure

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am reading data from sqlite using c#. The call is a get method. simultaneously 4 url's get called and to receive data I am using disconnected architecture. But sometimes i am getting exception as below,

1. Get item failed, reason:Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
2. Get item failed, reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
3. Connection was closed . Statement was terminated.

My execute code as below,

```
public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(String sqlExpr)
{
    SQLiteDataAdapter _adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlExpr, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    _adapter.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: at which line you are getting above two errors..  3rd one is simple that you need open connection before executing the adapter.fill statement..

Comment: thing = TzThing.Get(Convert.ToInt32(Id), SessionDatabase, langstr);
       if (thing == null)
             throw new Exception("requested item not found");

Comment: I guess open connection will solve the problem.

Comment: provide relevant code in question, your information is incomplete. To let another know about your problem describe it with detail relevant to the question ..